# Remote WinSCP commands not showing up

Tags: winscp

I have created this custom command in WinSCP with options as described:

```
description: &Find
command: find . -name "!?Search for files:?!"
remote command: enabled
show results in terminal: enabled
```

Problems:

1. When I right-click any of the remote directories, none of the remote commands are enabled (greyed out). Only local commands (e.g., print) is enabled.  Why is that?
2. When I add a new remote custom command, why is "apply to directories and execute recursively" disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer to the 1st one. You gotta SFTP it and not FTP.

But the second problem is still there. When I add a remote custom command, "apply to directories" and "execute recursively" are greyed out. Don't know why.

update: got the answer for second one too. it seems winscp is smart enough to determine which commands require those special options. for ex., when i typed tar those options were enabled but such was not the case for ps command.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP [Remote custom commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command) (as a kind of remote commands) work with the SCP only (and with the SFTP by fallback to the SCP).

*Apply to directories*: You need to have some file-related pattern in your command, such as the `!`.

*Execute recursively*: The same as the *Apply to directories*, except that you cannot use the `!&` or the `!^!`.

Both documented here (just click the *Help* button on the dialog):
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_customcommand